How to Authenticate Google Sign-In Users with Cognito in React Native Without Browser Redirection
I’m building a React Native app and using AWS Cognito for user authentication. I want to enable users to sign in with Google, but I’m facing issues integrating it smoothly with Cognito.
I Tried:
Using @react-native-google-signin/google-signin to get the Google ID Token:
await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
const idToken = userInfo.idToken; 

However, I’m unsure how to pass this idToken to Cognito to authenticate the user properly.
Using Cognito’s signInWithRedirect Method:
const user = await signInWithRedirect({ provider: 'Google' });

This works but opens a browser for the redirection, which is not ideal for a native app experience.
Issues:

Unverified Emails: When signing in with Google, Cognito marks the
email as unverified even though Google provides a verified email.
Duplicate Records: If a user previously signed up via email (e.g.,
user@example.com) and later uses Google Sign-In with the same email,
Cognito creates duplicate accounts instead of linking them.

Questions:

How do I authenticate a Google user with Cognito using the idToken
obtained from @react-native-google-signin/google-signin?
How can I ensure the email is marked as verified in Cognito after
Google Sign-In?
How do I prevent Cognito from creating duplicate accounts for the
same email address when users sign in with Google after registering
with email/password?

Any guidance or examples of implementing this in a React Native app would be greatly appreciated!
I’m using React Native with @react-native-google-signin/google-signin.
Cognito is configured for email/password authentication and Google as an Identity Provider
